# Getting when a signal emitted

Tags: qt, python-2.7, pyside

Is something like this possible for signals ?

```
while True:
        if signal is emitted:
                print "the signal is emitted"
```

Comment: You have it upside down. Instead of waiting for a signal's emission, you should simply connect your code to the signal.

Comment: The reason is, I am setting 4 different values from different combo boxes to a dictionary. So, when ever the data of combo boxes are changed and accepted with a push button (which later saved on a dict), I want to use the new data. because of that, I want to know when push button is emitting a signal to get the different values. @KubaOber

Comment: You're describing the most basic and common use of the signal-slot mechanism: nothing I said is in opposition to that. You'll probably want to read some PySide/PyQt tutorials to see how it's done. There is no reason for the "while True" loop, it'll make it not work.

Comment: `while True` would block the event loop and thus halt the whole program. I’d read up a bit on event-driven programming.